# VBA Invalid Picture error (But I'm not inserting any picture!)

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, vba, macros, microsoft-office-2010

I'm getting a very strange error in my Excel add-in. Every time that I open the .xlam file I got an `Invalid Picture` error. If I go to VBA using ALT+F11 and try to open any form, I also receive this error (Invalid Picture). The funny thing is that I managed to open one of the forms (with no error) but I can't tell why.

This same error is occurring in four machines that I tried to install the addin. The other funny thing is that all these four machines are desktops. I don't know why, but I managed to install fine in three laptops.

I've trying to reproduce the problem in my laptop but with no success. I also did not find the solution yet.

I can not get more information about the error because the error is occurring in a client. So, this is what I did to try to reproduce the problem in my laptop:

1. Block the `%TEMP%` folder for any read/write operation (no success);
2. Rename the `FM20.DLL` locate in system folder. I also used ProcMon to try figure it out the DLLs that is used by VBA and Excel but no success til now (there are plenty of things occurring that I still did not had the time to look after);
3. Tried to block the VBA access using gpedit.msc (no success).
4. To export a Form from my laptop (which works fine) to a computer that does not. In this case, I don't receive `Invalid Picture`. Instead, I got the below error when importing the form:

   ```
   System error &H80004005 (-2147467259).   Unspecified error
   ```

   and then

   ```
   Out of memory
   ```

   I managed to reproduce the above error in a Virtual Machine with disk full, but I cannot reproduce the `Invalid Picture` in my full disk VM.

And these are the things I've been trying to do to solve the problem:

1. To put the addin in the exceptions of the Symantec endpoint security (no success);
2. Reinstall office (no success);
3. Erasing the whole OS and installing everything from scratch (no success!) - after logging in the domain;

I got the very same error `Invalid Picture` if my addin is not installed and I try to open the Solver (that comes embedded with Excel). So the problem can't be my addin, right?

The IT people said to me that they tried to disable the security from Active Directory for the problematic machine, but no success as well, according to them.

I would bet on that there is something (perhaps the antivirus or the policies) blocking me to access a registry/file system. But who? And what?

Have anyone seen this error before?

The machines are Windows 7 32 bits using Office 2010.

I would really appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Renaming `FM20.DLL` will wreck any VBA project that uses UserForms. That is a type library that automatically gets referenced when you add a UserForm to a VBA project. Very, very very bad idea to tamper with it.

Comment: I would first look over the form to make sure it's not trying to display an image or icon.